# What happens if Noctis runs ahead too often in the mines?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

> After the battle in Altissa, Ignis becomes permanently blinded. While adjusting to his disability, Ignis remains part of the group and does his best to not be a hindrance.

*In Chapter 10: Heart of a King*, Gladio and Prompto hang back and assist Ignis through the mines while the player controls Noctis. During this mission, Gladio asks Noctis to stay close and not run too far ahead.

In moments when I put too much distance between Noctis and the rest of the party, Gladio would get angry and yell at Noctis to come back. I noticed that the more I ran off, the more my teammates seemed to assist Ignis more often and would move *slower* when I wasn't nearby.

Aside from Gladio sounding angry, is there an actual impact and effect of running ahead, and if so, how many times can Noctis run ahead before something happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From personal experience, the only real penalty of straying too far from the rest of the party is Gladio making you feel like a garbage human being (which is worse than any in-game penalty, imo).

All joking aside, it really just impacts how difficult the fights in the mines will be. If you're amply leveled past the recommended point and don't care about your brother-in-arms, then there doesn't seem to be a tangible in-game penalty. However, it's worth noting that I left everyone behind a few times and noticed that they would get stuck on obstacles and I'd have to go back to help them maneuver around them, which took quite a bit of extra time.

From [this guide](https://samurai-gamers.com/final-fantasy-15-ffxv/walkthrough-chapter-10-heart-king/), there does not seem to be a penalty aside from Ignis taking longer to catch up and assist you in battle, which, as mentioned above, would impact the difficulty of fights in the mines.

> Ignis walks slowly, so you also have to move at a slower pace for Ignis to catch up. Gladiolus will warn you if you stray too far from the party.

[This guide](http://guides.gamepressure.com/finalfantasyxv/guide.asp?ID=38043) also simply says you have to slow down in order for him to keep up, which, again, really just means that you'll have to wait for assistance if you stumble into a battle ahead of everyone.

> Additionally, he will be moving a lot slower - adjust your pace accordingly.